# Query values that are equal to true

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to make some easy achievement system. What should be the best way to do this? Right now I do like this to query achievements but like this I can't have badge type like bronze etc.:

```
databaseRef.child("usersAchievements").child(currentUser.generalDetails.uid).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in


            if snapshot.value as? Int == 1{
                self.achievements.append(snapshot.key)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }){ (error) in

        }
```

However I do not think it is the best way because I would like to display value like bronze or gold also inside tableview but right now it is not possible because I can't see to find how should I struct it.

Is it OK to have JSON struct like this:

```
allAchievements
 achievement1: 0 //e.g 0 is bronze and 1 is silver
 achievement2: 1


usersAchievements
  uFC7QFuY5rTUzxnXYlClrKobaQP2 //UID
     achievement1
       type: gold 
       username: true
     achievement2
       username: true
       type: silver
```

Or is it better to have JSON like this:

```
allAchievements
 achievement1: 0
 achievement2: 0


usersAchievements
  uFC7QFuY5rTUzxnXYlClrKobaQP2 //UID
     achievement1: true
     achievement2: true
```

I can't seem to find good answer for that.

I want to see achievements something like that inside tableview and the brown dot is bronze, gold or silver:

[image]

Comment: This question is very unclear. Are you asking if you should store true and false in firebase vs 1 and 0? Can you update your question so it's more clear what you are asking?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I am gonna update.

Comment: Are there any other achievements other than Bronze, Silver and Gold?

Comment: Ye it is just like SO badges some of them are gold some are silver etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the second option because it makes your tree even less complex. Personally I would refractor it even further.

First of, I would get rid of the `allAchievements` node. It seems rather redundant. Unless you plan on showing the user all the different achievements available, I'd just remove it. Plus as a user, the moment I see *bronze* as one of the achievements, I'd automatically assume that their's *silver* and *gold* or something along the lines. But even as a developer, you know all of your levels so you can simply list them down. All in all, I would get rid of the node.

Second, I would structure the achievements as such instead

```
usersAchievements
uFC7QFuY5rTUzxnXYlClrKobaQP2
bronze: true
silver: true
```

What happens when you want to update this? Two means

1. For each new `UUID` created, you can create all the achievement nodes by default and assign them a value of `false`. When an achievement is unlocked, you simply have to update the respective value.

   ```
   usersAchievements
   uFC7QFuY5rTUzxnXYlClrKobaQP2
   bronze: true // user earned this so its true
   silver: false // not earned so false but node already exists
   gold: false // not earned so false but node already exists
   ```
2. New achievements are created on an earned basis only.

   ```
   usersAchievements
   uFC7QFuY5rTUzxnXYlClrKobaQP2
   bronze: true // only one earned by the user
   ```

The first option is good because you would simply be updating each achievement node. But I think you can see how horrible/complex it will get when you have a lot of different achievements. You'll have a lot of data which is not relevant to the user.

The second option on the other hand, is guaranteed to have info relevant to a particular user but you'd have to keep track of the creation option.

**PS**: *Should you choose to go with the second option, you should handle the case when the node is empty; user hasn't earned any achievements, on the client-side*.

Comment: I do not have case when user doesn't have achievements since I give them one once registering :D But my achievements would be like "welcome" : true and it should have like is it bronze silver or gold.

Comment: Well that makes your life even easier..Yap. you can add `welcome: true` if that's the case.

Comment: But how would I struct it like welcome achievement is bronze type? And in tableview the dot color depends on that.

Comment: A welcome badge can simply be a welcome badge without any unlocked achievement. In your tableview you can choose any color to represent that and the moment your users start earning points enough to unlock an achievement, you can reflect the color respectively. Treat it as a newbie badge of some sort like [Waze](https://wiki.waze.com/wiki/Your_Rank_and_Points#Waze_Points_Level_.28in_client_app.29)

Comment: Ye but if I add achievement lets say user has 10 followers and now he earns achievement "wanted" true and I want to assign silver to it inside the JSON.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. I thought you said you have 3 achievements namely bronze, silver and gold. Where does "wanted" come from? Is it another achievement of some sorts?

Comment: I am so sorry if u misunderstood me. My point is to just have bunch of achievements with types like bronze, silver and gold like StackOverflow. But the problem is I do not know what would be the best struct for that and how to query then the achievements with the type like bronze

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126929/discussion-between-emil-david-and-tarvo-maesepp).

Answer (score 1):

If your achievements are dynamic, store them in a node, and keep an observer on them so if a new one it added, all clients are notified. You'll use this to populate a dictionary (e.g. achievementDict) in code to use as a lookup.

```
achievement_list
   -Uom9a9smmpasdm
       name: "Bronze"
   -Jiaiisiask9jkm
       name: "Silver"
   -Ykmsimiaooooos
       name: "Gold"
   -IJij00mlso09m9
       name: "Supa Dupa"
```

then for your users, keep a reference to their achievements within their user node

```
users
   -Yiniasopksdpok
      user_name: "Leroy Brown"
      achievements:
         -Ykmsimiaooooos: true
         -IJij00mlso09m9: true
   -JYimpoaosmoso
      user_name: "Marco Polo"
          achievements:
         -Uom9a9smmpasdm: true
```

With this, you know thay Leroy has Gold and is Supa Dupa and Marco Polo is Silver.

You want to use the actual names of the achievements "Bronze", "Silver" etc and those are kept in a dictionary in your app that's updated if a new achievement is added.

When your user list (or whatever) is displayed you can just look up each achievement from that dictionary by it's key.

```
let achievementName = achievementDict["-IJij00mlso09m9"]
```

would retrieve Supa Dupa